# setState() called in constructor: InvestorState#5d7b8(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Investor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Investor> createState() => InvestorState();
}

List<InvestorList> investorList = [];

class InvestorState extends State<Investor> {
  List<InvestorList> investorLIST = [];
  void addInvestor({required String name, required int taka}) {
    final investor = InvestorList(investorName: name, investorTaka: taka);
    investorLIST.add(investor);
    // setState(() {
    //   investorLIST;
    // });
    setState(() {});
  }

  List<Widget> widgetList() {
    List<Widget> widgetMakingList = [];
    setState(() {
      investorLIST;
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < investorLIST.length; i++) {
      widgetMakingList.add(Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '${investorLIST[i].investorName!}\n'
            'investing amount:${investorLIST[i].investorTaka!} taka',
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Times new Roman'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));
    }
    return widgetMakingList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      investorLIST = investorList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView(
        children: widgetList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InvestorList {
  final String investorName;
  final int investorTaka;
  InvestorList({required this.investorName, required this.investorTaka});
}
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Investor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Investor> createState() => _InvestorState();
}

List<InvestorList> investorList = [];

class _InvestorState extends State<Investor> {

  void addInvestor({required String name, required int taka}) {
    final investor = InvestorList(investorName: name, investorTaka: taka);
    investorList.add(investor);
    // setState(() {
    //   investorList;
    // });
    setState(() {});
  }

  List<Widget> widgetList() {
    List<Widget> widgetMakingList = [];
    setState(() {
      investorList;
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < investorList.length; i++) {
      widgetMakingList.add(Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '${investorList[i].investorName!}\n'
            'investing amount:${investorList[i].investorTaka!} taka',
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Times new Roman'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));
    }
    return widgetMakingList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      investorList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView(
        children: widgetList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InvestorList {
  final String investorName;
  final int investorTaka;
  InvestorList({required this.investorName, required this.investorTaka});
}
```

I am trying to do this that whenever the investorList is getting updated then the widget should be recreated. But it is not. I know that the investorList should be inside the class _InvestorState but investorList will be accessed from other classes.I have tried a lot how to update the widget,i have used setSate but it also didn't help me. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `setState` synchronously from the `initState` because `setState` is triggering the `build` method and `initState` is called before the first call to `build`, this is what is implied by "widget is not mounted".

You can call `setState` only if your widget is [mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) here's what is said in the Flutter documentation:

> After creating a State object and before calling initState, the
> framework "mounts" the State object by associating it with a
> BuildContext. The State object remains mounted until the framework
> calls dispose, after which time the framework will never ask the State
> object to build again.

It is an error to call setState unless mounted is true.

You should be able to trigger a rebuild when your variable `investorList` is edited by calling `setState` from your `addInvestor` method but you'll have to define what should be the trigger that'll call `addInvestor`.

### Code sample

```dart
class _InvestorState extends State<Investor> {
  final investorList = <InvestorList>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          for (final e in investorList) ...[
            Text(
              '${e.investorName}\n'
              'investing amount:${e.investorTaka} taka',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Times new Roman'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            const Divider(color: Colors.black87, thickness: 5),
          ],
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void addInvestor({required String name, required int taka}) {
    final investor = InvestorList(investorName: name, investorTaka: taka);
    investorList.add(investor);
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

[Try the full code sample on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4232f598b80f7d9932da9c98d6cb7f9b)

Comment: Thank you.But if i want to access the investorList which is global.then what can i do?

Comment: @Atik19 it would be a bad practice to keep investorList as a global but if you don't have another choice you could consider creating a `ChangeNotifier` to hold the value and add a listener on it to call setState.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in your initState. this will only run once your widget tree is mounted

```
if(mounted){
  setState(() {
   investorLIST = investorList;
  });
}
```